# Update button doesnt work as there is a type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

There is an error in type mismatch on  rowselect = Search.BN.Value . I want to let user edit and update the excel sheet , the excel sheet is called"Master".
The error msg: Run time error "13" Type mismatch.

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

Dim Bname As String

Bname = Search.BN.Text

Sheets("MASTER").Select

Dim rowselect As Integer
Dim ans As String

rowselect = Search.BN.Value
rowselect = rowselect + 1
Rows(rowselect).Select


Sheets("MASTER").Cells(rowselect, 6) = Search.A.Text
Sheets("MASTER").Cells(rowselect, 7) = Search.Emailto.Text
Sheets("MASTER").Cells(rowselect, 8) = Search.CClist.Text
Sheets("MASTER").Cells(rowselect, 9) = Search.Emailcc.Text

rowselect = rowselect - 1

Unload Me

ans = MsgBox("S/N " & rowselect & "  Successfully Updated...Continue?", vbYesNo, "Update")
If ans = vbYes Then
    Search.Show
Else
    Sheets("MASTER").Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of  Search.BN.Value when the error occurs? Presumably it is text intended to be implicitly converted to a number which won't happen for empty string literal. Can it ever be blank? Also, use Long not Integer.

Comment: Please can you include the whole error message that you received?

Comment: `Dim rowselect As LONG ... rowselect = CLNG(Search.BN.Value)`

Comment: hi @QHarr . The Search.BN.Value is the value in the BN textbox

Comment: hi @Jeeped , the error messsage still appear :(

Comment: See @Jeeped's comment and also you need to handle if empty string or string that can't be cast as numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a test to see if can be converted and declare as variant to capture any error on conversion. Then test if error was produced to branch program. The below is illustrative.

```
Public Sub TEST()
    Dim s As String
    'this is illustrative. You would incorporate this so  Search.BN.Value was available
    s = Search.BN.Value
    Dim rowSelect As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    rowSelect = CLng(s)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If IsError(rowSelect) Then Exit Sub

    'Your other code......
End Sub
```